# CardView does not wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout

Iam trying to use cardView widget with horizontal orientation to show some information like that:
[Explanation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZA3u.png)

if you notice that the textView doen't full appear in case that the screen size is small or i rotate the screen, i tried to wrap content in CardView and Horizontal view but it doesn't work, and this is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".PhotoDetail">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/Card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/photo_author"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photo_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/place_holder" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/photo_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/photo_tags"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>


 </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: make hierarchy `CardView->ScrollView->LinearLayout` instead of `ScrollView->CardView->LinearLayout`  this way content will be scroll if it goes outside of screen . I am not sure about your expected output though.

Comment: Please make it as a answer because it works

Comment: Glad it worked for you . You can add an answer yourself  With updated code and accept it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after changes the hierarchy from: `ScrollView->CardView->LinearLayout` to `CardView->ScrollView->LinearLayout` . it becomes scrollable in CardView widget it self, the code after editting:

````
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PhotoDetail">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/Card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/photo_author"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/photo_img"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/place_holder" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/photo_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/photo_tags"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Change your ScrollVIew layout_height = "match_parent" to layout_height = "wrap_content"

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/Card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/photo_author"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photo_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/place_holder" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/photo_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/photo_tags"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am bit confused what is your problem now? is your CardView not scrolling? Please clarify more  clearly. I am waiting for your comment. !